# Dropdown Menu for Query_Posts

Tags: php, query-posts, dropdown

I can successfully query post results using query posts like so...

```
<?php

// The Query
query_posts("gdsr_sort=rating");

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php 
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

I was wondering if it's possible to make a dropdown menu where users can select different queries. So an example would a dropdown menu that says "Select Query" by deafult then when you click the dropdown menu it gives you different options like "Query 1", "Query 2", Query 3".. and when you click on one it loads the correct query for whatever query is set to number 1, 2, or 3.

I've done a lot of research and haven't found too much help regarding this issue. I don't know if I should set up an `if / else` statement connect that to the `<select>` input and then.. I don't know where to go from there.. or if that is even a proper way of doing it.

So, how would I make a dropdown menu that successfully loads different post queries?  Any help would truly be appreciated. :)

Comment: You are talking about basic PHP. Look up "creating processing form PHP".

Comment: @s_ha_dum Creating a dropdown that takes any page that a user is currently on and applies a query to it is basic php? really? I've searched a lot of different things on google to find a solution to this question and have yet to find an example or anything like that.  I appreciate your comment, but if it is truely basic PHP, it wouldn't hurt to give an answer.  And I will google "creating processing form PHP" while im at it. thanks. :)

Comment: Close-voted as **not a real question**: "*It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*" Yes, this can be done, but the question scope is so overly broad as to constitute *work for me for free*. Have a look at **[`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)** for adding query parameters from your select field and **[`get_query_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)** for retrieving/using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of a PHP dropdown, hope this helps.

```
<select name="mydropdownlist">
<?php
    $options = array('option1' => 'option 1'
                 'option2' => 'option 2'
                 'option3' => 'option 3');

    foreach($options as $value => $caption)
   {
        echo "<option value=\"$value\">$caption</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a dropdown menu like (in HTML):

```
<select name="query">
    <option value="0">Select Query</option>
    <option value="1">Query 1</option>
    <option value="2">Query 2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

And then use the following PHP:

```
$query = '';

switch( $_POST['query'] ) {
    case '2':
        $query = ''; // your query
        break;
    case '1':
        $query = ''; // your query
        break;
    default:
    case '0':
        $query = 'gdsr_sort=rating';
        break;
}

// The Query
query_posts( $query );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php 
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```